# No me esta llegando nada por $_POST['public'] en mi formulario

Tags: php, html5

Estoy teniendo un problema que no logro solucionar, tengo un formulario pero cuando oprimo el botón de publicar no me esta llegando nada del lado del backend, los **$_POST** me están llegando vacío y he precurado que la etiqueta **form** de mi formulario todo este correcto pero no me esta llagando la información

He colocado un `var_dump();` pero dice que esta nulo, lo que quiere decir que no me esta llegando nada por **POST**

Creo que el problema esta en la parte del Frontend, pero no logro identificar el error, no logro saber porque no esta llegando la información por POST.

La pagina donde esta la logica de PHP esta en un `require_once();` dentro de la misma pagina donde esta el Frontend.

**HTML FORM:**

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="POST" class="col s12" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="row">

                        <!-- Imagen -->
                        <div class="file-field input-field col s12">
                            <div class="btn">
                                <span>Imagen</span>
                                <input type="file" name="imagen" accept="image/*" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                                <input class="file-path validate" type="text" placeholder="Selecciona la miniatura de la entrada">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Titulo -->
                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <i class="material-icons prefix grey-text">title</i>
                            <input id="title" type="text" name="title" value="" class="validate" minlength="21" maxlength="100" required />
                            <label for="title">Titulo</label>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Descripcion -->
                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <i class="material-icons prefix grey-text">description</i>
                            <textarea id="description" name="description" class="materialize-textarea" minlength="65" maxlength="100" required></textarea>
                            <label for="description">Descripci&oacute;n. Max 100 carateres</label>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Cuerpo -->
                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <i class="material-icons prefix grey-text">web</i>
                            <textarea id="cuerpo" name="cuerpo" class="materialize-textarea" required></textarea>
                            <label for="cuerpo">Cuerpo de la noticia</label>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Etiquetas -->
                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <i class="material-icons prefix grey-text">text_fields</i>
                            <input id="etiquetas" type="text" name="etiquetas" class="validate" required />
                            <label for="etiquetas">Etiquetas. Separar con ","</label>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Credito -->
                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <i class="material-icons prefix grey-text">images</i>
                            <input id="credito" type="text" name="credito" class="validate" maxlength="240" />
                            <label for="credito">Credito a la miniatura</label>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Boton publicar -->
                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <div class="input-field col s3">
                                <button type="submit" name="public" class="waves-effect green btn">
                                <i class="material-icons left">send</i> Publicar
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                </form>
```

**CODIGO PHP:**

```
<?php

$email = $_SESSION['email'];

// Declarando variables
$statusBlog = 'yes';
$error = '';
$success = '';
$maxSize = 2097152; // 2 MB

// Obtener direccion ip del cliente
$ipBlog = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

// Obtener el navegador del visitante
$browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$browser = getBrowserName($browser);


// Sacar el nombre del usuario registrado
$stmt = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");
$stmt->execute(['email' => $email]);
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $id_user_blog = $row['id_usuario'];
}

if(isset($_POST['public'])){

    $imagen = $_POST['imagen'];
    var_dump($descriptionNotice);
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $descriptionNotice = $_POST['description'];
    $cuerpo = $_POST['cuerpo'];
    $keyword = $_POST['etiquetas'];
    $credito = $_POST['credito'];

    // Validar que credito, etiquetas y descripcion sea menor a 255 carateres
    $creditoMax = strlen($credito);
    if($creditoMax >= 240){
        $error .= 'Has superado el maximo de 240 carateres en los creditos de la imagen';
    }

    $keywordMax = strlen($keyword);
    if($keywordMax >= 240){
        $error .= 'Has superado el maximo de 240 carateres en las keyword';
    }

    $descriptionNoticeMax = strlen($descriptionNotice);
    if($descriptionNoticeMax >= 100){
        $error .= 'Has superado el maximo de 100 carateres en la descripci&oacute;n de la noticia';
    }

    // validar que algunos campos no esten vacios
    if(empty($imagen)){
        $error .= 'Debes colocar una imagen para la noticia';
    }

    if(empty($title)){
        $error .= 'El titulo no puede estar vacio';
    }

    if(empty($descriptionNotice)){
        $error .= 'La descripci&oacute;n es obligatoria';
    }

    if(empty($cuerpo)){
        $error .= 'El cuerpo de la noticia es obligatorio';
    }

    // Tamaño Maximo de la Imagen
    if($imagen['size'] >= $maxSize) {
        $error .= 'La Imagen pesa mucho, por favor solo 2MB <br/>';
    }

    // Verificar que las fotos de producto sean de tipo imagenes
    $imagenName = $imagen['name'];
    $imagenType = $imagen['type'];

    if($imagenType == "image/jpg" || $imagenType == "image/jpeg" || $imagenType == "image/png" || $imagenType == "image/git" || $imagenType == "image/gif"){

        if(!is_dir('./blog_foto')){
            mkdir('./blog_foto', 0777);
        }

        move_uploaded_file($imagen['tmp_name'], './blog_foto/'.$imagenName);

    }else{
        $errors = 'Has introducido un archivo como Imagen que no es soportado <br/>';
    }

    // Si todo esta bien, entonces guardamos toda la informacion en la base de datos
    if($error == ''){
        $statement = $conexion->prepare('INSERT INTO blog (id_blog, id_user_blog, title_blog, body, description_blog, foto_blog, keyword, credito_foto, status_blog, ip_blog, browser_blog, create_at_blog) VALUES(
            null, :id_user_blog, :title, :cuerpo, :descriptionNotice, :imagenName, :keyword, :credito, :statusBlog, :ipBlog, :browser, NOW())'
        );
        $statement->execute(array(
            ':name' => $name,
            ':assunt' => $assunt,
            ':email' => $email,
            ':message' => $message,
            ':ip' => $ip,
            ':browser' => $browser
        ));

        $success = 'Tu noticia se ha publicado con &eacute;xito';
    }

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué `var_dump` colocaste exactamente? Pon un `var_dump($_POST);` y dinos qué muestra. Tu problema más bien está en la forma de buscar ciertos datos, por ejemplo, en los formularios donde mandas archivos, debes usar `$_FILES` para recuperar esos archivos, no `$_POST`. Como prueba, pon también un `var_dump($_FILES);`

Comment: Gracias amigo, el problema estaba en que no estaba colocando el `$_FILES`, ay ahora todos los datos están llegando correctamente. Responde a mi pregunta de manera oficial para colocar tu respuesta como aceptada y darle un like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ten en cuenta que tu formulario está definido como `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, que es lo correcto para pasar archivos junto con los datos normales.

Pero para recuperar los archivos debes usar `$_FILES`, no `$_POST`, que sirve solamente para los elementos que no sean del tipo `file`.

Para más detalle sobre esto, consulta el [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/features.file-upload.post-method.php):

> El array global [`$_FILES`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.files.php) contendrá toda la información de los
> los ficheros subidos. ...